# find: ‘count=1’: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, find

Previous code:

```
total=`ls -Rp rootfs | wc -l`
count=0
```

When I assign a simple addition to a variable:

```
sudo find rootfs -exec cp -d -- "{}" "/media/$USER/{}" 2> /dev/null \; -exec sync \; -exec count=$((count+1)) \; -exec echo -en "\rcopiati: $count/$total" \;
```

I get:

```
find: ‘count=1’: No such file or directory
```

Also when I exec:

```
sudo find rootfs -exec cp -d -- "{}" "/media/$USER/{}" 2> /dev/null \; -exec sync \; -exec count=1 \; -exec echo -en "\rcopiati: $count/$total" \;
```

I get the same error. Why?

For each file copied i want the counter: 1/13444, that is updated to 2/13444, 3/13444, etc...

edit:

I have found a method but it doesn't see hidden files, how can I make them see them in a for loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
copysync() {
    countfiles() {
        for f in $1/*; do
            if [ -d "$f" ]; then
                countfiles "$f"
            else
                if [ "${f: -2}" != "/*" ]; then
                    total=$((total+1))
                fi
            fi
        done
    }
    recursivecp() {
        for f in $1/*; do
            if [ -d "$f" ]; then
                mkdir -p "/media/$USER/$f"
                recursivecp "$f"
            else
                if [ "${f: -2}" != "/*" ]; then
                    sudo cp -a "$f" "/media/$USER/$f"
                    sudo sync
                    count=$((count+1))
                    echo -en "\rCopied: $((count*100/total))%"
                fi
            fi
        done
    }
    total=0
    countfiles $1
    count=0
    recursivecp $1
}
copysync rootfs
```

Comment: Why aren't you just executing a single `sh -c` in-line script? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705

Answer (score 5):

The shell expands `count=$((count+1))` before running `find`.

Then `find` will try to execute the argument to `-exec` as a command. This must be a program or script, it cannot be a shell builtin or shell syntax for variable assignment.

Counting the files found does not work this way because `find` starts a new process for `-exec`, so the result of a variable assignment would not be available in the parent shell.

I suggest to print a line for every file found and pipe the output of `find` to `wc -l`, for example

```
find rootfs -exec cp -d -- "{}" "/media/$USER/{}" \; -exec sync \; -print|wc -l
```

To get some output while copying the files you can use something like this:

```
find rootfs|while IFS= read -r file
do
    cp -d -- "$file" "/media/$USER/$file"
    sync
    count=$((count+1))
    echo -en "\rcopiati: $count/$total"
done
```

Remarks:

This does not work for file names that contain a newline (and maybe other special characters).

The script may not work if `rootfs` contains subdirectories. You should either handle this case or use `find`'s options `-maxdepth` and `-type f` to avoid this problem.

Comment: wc: opzione non valida -- "e"
Try 'wc --help' for more information.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Where does option `e` (`-e`) come from? My command contains `wc -l`, it doesn't contain option `e`.

Comment: sudo find rootfs -exec cp -d -- "{}" "/media/$USER/{}" \; -exec sync \; -print|wc -l \; -exec echo -en "\rcopiati: $count/$total" \;

Comment: This is not what I suggested. Try my command first and explain your requirements for the output in your question.

Comment: For each file copied i want the progression: 1/13444, that is updated to 2/13444, 3/13444, etc

Comment: Write this **in your question**.

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca How do you calculate the value `total`? Please answer this **in your question**.

Comment: I have write this in my question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you're trying to execute each and every command with `-exec`.  This would not work in the general case as `-exec` only executes external commands.

Instead, call a single in-line script and let `find` act as a generator for a loop in that script:

```
find rootfs -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        cp -d "$pathname" "/media/$USER" &&
        echo . &&
        sync
    done' sh {} + | wc -l
```

This would find all regular files in or below the `rootfs` directory.  For batches of these files, a short inline `sh -c` script is called.  This script copies each file to the given directory, outputs a dot followed by a newline for each successfully copied file, and calls `sync`.

The `wc -l` counts the number of dots outputted and reports this count. We don't count the pathnames themselves as this count would be misleading if any pathname contains an embedded newline character.

Without using `find`, this can be done in e.g. `bash` like so:

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

for pathname in rootfs/**/*; do
    [[ ! -f $pathname ]] && continue
    cp -d "$pathname" "/media/$USER" &&
    echo . &&
    sync
done | wc -l
```

This uses a globbing pattern containing the `**` glob which matches down inte subdirectories if the `globstar` shell option is set.  I also set `dotglob` to be able to see hidden names, and the `nullglob` shell option to avoid running the loop at all if the pattern doesn't match anything.

The same thing, but with a counter:

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

count=0
for pathname in rootfs/**/*; do
    [[ ! -f $pathname ]] && continue
    cp -d "$pathname" "/media/$USER" &&
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    sync
done
printf 'count=%d\n' "$count"
```

Comment: sync must be inside the loop after copy command.

Comment: sh --help not work

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca 1st comment) Ok, so move the sync into the loop. 2nd comment) No it wouldn't, try `man sh`. `sh` is the standard shell.

Comment: tank you for the second. Also count have to be for each file. As explain in the question. The same line have to be updated (echo en "\r..." (is for carriage return)) with 1/14333, 2/14333, 3/14333, etc...

Comment: What means "/**/*"?

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca The pattern `rootfs/**/*` matches each and every name in or under the `rootfs` directory. The `**` bit of the pattern matches zero or more subdirectory levels. The `*` at the end matches all names in any subdirectory.